# Change directory name if another exist with the same name

Tags: java

thank you very much for reading the question, what i want to do is to create a folder/directory 
in an specific path, but, if there already is a folder with the same name make a folder called "foldername 1" if this already exist make "foldername 2", "foldername 3"... "foldername n". I am using java.

Comment: Check if it exists and if so, change the name you want to write. Really that's it.

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: This isn't a question, it's a list of requirements, which means it's more "do my job for me".

Comment: I've already did it a just need how to put the numbers at the end. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple function take the path of the directory and a number (0 if you don't know how many folders are already made).
It check if the folder exist and add a number if it is already made, and recursively check for other numbers.

```
public void newFolder(String Path, int n) {

    File folder;
    if(n==0) 
        folder = new File(Path);
    else
        folder = new File(Path +" "+ n);

    if(folder.exists()) 
        newFolder(Path, ++n);
    else
        folder.mkdir();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is just a simple, and I really stress the word simple check:

```
public class CheckFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileToCheck = "C:/Users/Bla/Desktop/Test";

        File f = new File(fileToCheck);
        if(f.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("File or folder : " + fileToCheck + " already exists");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("File or folder : " + fileToCheck + " does not exists");
        }
    }
}
```

But that's a case of 1min searching ;) Good documented APIs like the Java Documentation are a powerful source of information.